# Is unused npm library code still part of the final compiled project?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I’m working on a react project. If I install a library, but only use one small part of it. Is the entire library part of the final compiled project, or just the parts used?

Comment: If you're asking about what code is built into client side bundled javascript files (as opposed to what runs in node.js, or what's published to npm if you're making a package), then it depends on your bundler that you're using. Webpack and rollup both do "tree shaking" which is probably what you want to research.

Comment: For example:
I have a react component that uses the Button component from the @mui/material library.  That Button component is the only component used from that library.  When the project is compiled to put it in production, will the entire @mui/material library code be part of the code in production. Or will the Button component be the only library code that part of the code in production?

Comment: As mentioned, it depends on your bundler. [This blog post](https://andrewray.me/blog/webpack-when-to-use-and-why) might be a helpful intro to webpack

Comment: I created the project with create-react-app.  So, it does include webpack.